# Diagnostics setting for azure VM

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-virtual-machine, azure-diagnostics, iaas

If i enable diagnostic setting for vm in azure and send it to storage account.

I can't able to specify retention period.

Should we manually delete the older logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you send the logs to storage account, there is no way to configure the retention day. You need to delete it manually.

But there is a feature [azure storage lifecycle management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-lifecycle-management-concepts?tabs=azure-portal), you can use this feature to define a `delete policy`. For example, define a `delete policy` for a specific blob/container which can be deleted after x days.